# Find the population size that maximizes the probability that two random samples of size $20$ will have exactly $2$ members in common

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Ten fish are caught in a lake, marked, and then returned to the lake. Two days later 20 fish are again caught, 2 of which have been marked.

(a) Find the probability of 2 of the 20 fish being marked if the lake has $k$ fish (assuming the fish are caught at random).
(b) What value of k maximizes the probability?

---

*Progress*:     I got the (a), $$\binom{10}{2}\binom{k-10}{18}\bigg/ \binom{k}{20}$$ But how do I get part (b) where $k$ is to maximize the probability?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I got the (a) --> (10 C 2)* ((k-10) C 18) /(k C 20). but how do i get part (b) where k = ?? --> maximize the probability? please help. Thanks in advance! I

Answer (score 2):

That looks right for $P(k)$.  For (b), calculate $P(k+1)/P(k)$, and find when it is greater than, or less than, $1$.

Comment: I tried and ended up with (k-9)/((k-27)*k). then what to do. how does it help

Comment: Let that equal 1, and rearrange it.  It turns into a quadratic.

Comment: @Michael Actually, no, the equation has degree one. But the answer is nice. +1